# fail to download jpg file in chrome using https connection

Tags: web, https, http-headers

I'm creating a button, that will download a jpg file when you click it. What Im doing is that redirect to a hyperlinking to the img file and setting the content-type and content-disposition headers there using the code below

```
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fullpath));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filename));
    readfile($fullpath);
```

$fullpath is the pysical location of the jpg file

it works fine in chrome IE and firefox in my develop website, which used http connection.

but when I put it the live website, which uses https connection, IE and firefox still works fine, but chrome sometimes works, sometime it will show a page with messed up strings instead of download the jpg file. I think maybe chrome didn't recognize the MIME type of the jpg file and treat it as plain text. This is pretty odd (sometime it could recognize the jpg file and download it, sometime not) . Has anyone got the same problem before or has any idea to fix this?